# How to COUNT duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, histogram

I want to be able to create a histogram out of a tuple containing two integers values.

Here it is the query:

```
 SELECT temp.ad_id, temp.distance  as hits FROM ( 
 'UNION ALL .join(cupound_query)' # python
) as temp GROUP BY temp.ad_id,temp.distance
```

For this input:

```
(51, 5)
(51, 0)
(51, 3)
(51, 0)
(88, 2)
(88, 2)
(88, 2)
(84, 1)
(81, 9)
```

Would be:

```
(88,2) : 3
(51,0) : 2
(51,3) : 1
(51,5) : 1
(84,1) : 1
(81,9) : 1
```

How can I create a histogram of those values?
In other words, how can I count how many times a row has a duplicate?

Comment: How do you define duplicate?  It looks like your current dataset has no duplicates, which makes it a bad representative sample for your question.  Are you thinking counting the number of hits in, say ranges of 50,  like 400-450, 450-500, 500-550, etc?  If so please clarify.

Comment: duplicate in the sense, exact same numbers on both sides. Yes, in the sample I gave there would be a COUNT = 1 for each element

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The question leaves room for interpretation. This test case shows 2 nested steps:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (ad_id int, distance int);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (510, 0), (956, 3), (823, 3), (880, 2)
, (523, 3), (467, 0), (843, 1), (816, 9)
, (533, 4), (721, 7), (288, 3), (900, 3)
, (526, 9), (750, 7), (302, 8), (463, 6)
, (742, 8), (804, 2), (62,  7), (880, 2)
, (523, 3), (467, 0), (843, 1), (816, 9)
, (533, 4), (721, 7), (288, 3), (900, 3)
, (526, 9), (750, 7), (302, 8), (816, 9)
, (533, 4), (721, 7), (288, 3), (900, 3)
, (533, 4), (721, 7), (288, 3), (396, 5)
;
```

#### How many duplicates per value?

```
SELECT ad_id, count(*) AS ct FROM tbl GROUP BY 1;
```

Result:

```
ad_id  | ct
-------+----
62     | 1
288    | 4
302    | 2
396    | 1
...
```

Read: *`ad_id 62` exists 1x, `ad_id 288` exists 4x, ...*

#### How to count how many times rows have duplicates?

```sql
SELECT ct, count(*) AS ct_ct
FROM  (SELECT ad_id, count(*) AS ct FROM tbl GROUP BY 1) sub
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Result:

```
 ct | ct_ct
----+-------
1   | 8
2   | 7
3   | 2
4   | 3
```

Read: *8 occurrences of "`ad_id` is unique", 7 occurrences of "2 rows with same `ad_id`", ...*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=852d1e2bd6b70ae774b95fcb3edac9dc)*

Answer (score 2):

Just add `count(*)` to your select:

```
SELECT temp.ad_id, temp.distance as hits, count(*)
....
```